# KMeans To Find Dominant Color of Each Image in an Array of Images

Tags: python-3.x, k-means, image-recognition

I am trying to use K-Means to find the dominant color of each image in an array of images.  The example below uses KMeans from python's sklearn.cluster import.

Say, for example, I have a 100x100 pixel image, I would like to find the dominant color of 5x5 blocks within the 100x100 image.

My current implementation (below) is using K-Means to analyze each 5x5 block one at a time, which is extremely slow for larger image sizes.  I would like to feed an array of images in to K-Means and have it return an array of dominant colors, where each index in the returned array corresponds to the index in the images array.

Current implementation:

```
def get_dominant_color(image):
    image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))

    clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 4)
    labels = clt.fit_predict(image)
    label_counts = Counter(labels)
    dominant_color = clt.cluster_centers_[label_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]]

    divisor = np.sum(dominant_color)
    if divisor != 0:
        # normalize the rgb values
        dominant_color = dominant_color / np.sum(dominant_color)

    return dominant_color
```

I've tried modifying this to call `clt.fit_predict(images)`, where images is an array of 5x5 blocks, but I believe this will mix in all the colors of all the images to produce a single output.  If possible, how can I manipulate this to independently analyze each individual image?